# Python dataclasses: assign variable to field in a frozen instance from input

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I want to create an **immutable** class that reads a file and do other things. I have problems with the mutability:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

import io


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Book:
    
    filename: str
    #file: io.TextIOWrapper
    
    def __new__(cls, filename):
        
        self = super().__new__(cls)
        
        self.file = open(filename, "r")
        
        return self
    
    
    def __post_init__(self):
        
        #self.file = open(self.filename, "r")
        
        pass
    
    
    def close(self):
        
        self.file.close()

book = Book("testfile.txt")
book.close()
print(book)
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Sync1\Code\Python3\EconoPy\Version_0.2\test.py", line 32, in <module>
    book = Book("testfile.txt")
  File "D:\Sync1\Code\Python3\EconoPy\Version_0.2\test.py", line 17, in __new__
    self.file = open(filename, "r")
  File "<string>", line 4, in __setattr__
dataclasses.FrozenInstanceError: cannot assign to field 'file'
```

I want to set the attribute `self.file` from the input `filename`, but the 'frozening' is forbidding that. With the `__post_init__` I can do that if I remove the 'frozening'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment this looks like an inappropriate use of a dataclass.

Opening the file when the class is instantiated and having a `close` method... this looks like a glorified file object so far - maybe it would be better as a subclass of `TextIOWrapper`?

Or as a context manager? https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager

Anyway, for sake of answering your question as asked, we can find the solution in the docs here https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#frozen-instances
...we can bypass the enforcement of immutability by using `object.__setattr__`.

So a working example would look like:

```py
import io
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Book:
    
    filename: str
    file: io.TextIOWrapper = field(init=False)
    
    def __post_init__(self):
        object.__setattr__(self, "file", open(self.filename, "r"))

    def close(self):
        self.file.close()
```

Comment: About "At the moment this looks like an inappropriate use of a dataclass.". This is an example, the real code is about reading an `.xls` file with the `xlrd` module and produce an generator. It is some kind of lazy reading.

Comment: Just generally I think it's weird using a _data_ class as the basis for a context manager

Comment: I did this way because I want to have multiple "readers". I mean, different classes for different file extensions. I try to emulate the Python `readlines` method with a generator/iterator over the rows of a table. Of course, making a `yield` function is another option.

Answer (score 2):

One option here which would avoid calling `object.__setattr__` would be to do the following:

1. Set the file field to have a default value of None
2. Add an `open` function which returns a replacement dataclass object that has the same filename but opens the file and stores it in the file field of the new object.

```
import dataclasses
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

import io

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Book:

    filename: str
    file: io.TextIOWrapper = field(default=None)

    def open(self):
        return dataclasses.replace(self, file=open(self.filename))

    def close(self):
        self.file.close()


book = Book("testfile.txt")
book = book.open()
book.close()
print(book)  # Book(filename='testfile.txt', file=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='testfile.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>)
```

Got the idea from this article: https://python.plainenglish.io/why-and-how-to-write-frozen-dataclasses-in-python-69050ad5c9d4

Comment: Your solution is valid, although I don't select it because the `book = book.open()` line is easy to forget. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: That's fair.  I think a similar approach could be used with `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods if you wanted to create a context manager for your dataclass, but I haven't actually tested that yet.  Of course, once you're making it a context manager, it should probably just be a normal class.